# Unexplained Validation Errors in my Fast API

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm Writing a timesheet API That has the fields TimeSheet_Id, Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Date, hours. So far I can get it to Create new Time sheet objects and upload them onto a sqlite Database, So there doesn't seem to be an error when using a post request, but when I try to retrieve data from it, for example retrieving all entries with an Employee_Id equal to 1, it just gives me the validation error list bellow:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 5 validation errors for TimeSheet
response -> Sheet_Id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> Employee_Id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> Employee_Name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> Date
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> hours
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

All the forums I have checked that have this error show up usually happen when they preform a post request and not a get request like mine. Here is what my main.py looks like:

```
from email.policy import HTTP
from http.client import HTTPException
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, status
from requests import session
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from database import Base, SessionLocal, engine
from typing import List
import models
import schema

app = FastAPI()

#Create Database
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

#Get DB
def get_session():
    session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return "TimeSheet app"

@app.post("/TimeSheet", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_TimeSheet(timesheet: schema.TimeSheetCreate, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):

    timesheet_db  = models.TimeSheetDB(Employee_Id= timesheet.Employee_Id, Employee_Name = timesheet.Employee_Name, Date = timesheet.Date, hours = timesheet.hours)

    session.add(timesheet_db)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(timesheet_db)

    session.close
    return session

@app.get("/TimeSheets/{id}", response_model=schema.TimeSheet)
def get_TimeSheet(e_id:int):

    session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)

    sheet_list = session.query(models.TimeSheetDB)\
        .filter(models.TimeSheetDB.Employee_Id == e_id)\
        .all()
    
    session.close
    return sheet_list

@app.get("/TimeSheet/{id}", response_model=schema.TimeSheet)
def get_TimeSheetDate(date:str, e_id:int, year:int, month:int, day:int):

    session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)

    sheet_list = session.query(models.TimeSheetDB)\
        .filter(models.TimeSheetDB.Employee_Id==e_id, models.TimeSheetDB.Date == date(year,month,day))\
        .all()
    session.close
    return sheet_list
```

Here's schema.py:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date
#Create Timesheet Model
class TimeSheetCreate(BaseModel):
    Employee_Id:int
    Employee_Name:str
    Date:date
    hours:int

class TimeSheet(BaseModel):
    Sheet_Id:int
    Employee_Id:int
    Employee_Name:str
    Date:date
    hours:int

    class Config:
        orm_mode=True
```

And Here's models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column, Date
from database import Base
class TimeSheetDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TimeSheets"
    TimeSheet_Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Employee_Id = Column(Integer)
    Employee_Name = Column(String(50))
    Date = Column(Date)
    hours = Column(Integer)
```

Comment: add endpoint and request payload and update the question

Comment: There is no need to reference `session.close` (which you only reference, but do not call either) in your view functions - the `get_db` dependency will handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

you return list of objects so you should edit response model like that:

```py
@app.get("/TimeSheets/{e_id}", response_model=List[schema.TimeSheet])
def get_TimeSheet(e_id:int):

    session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)

    sheet_list = session.query(models.TimeSheetDB)\
        .filter(models.TimeSheetDB.Employee_Id == e_id)\
        .all()
    
    session.close()
    return sheet_list
```